# Relationship between contact and opportunity

Tags: soql, opportunity, contact, related-list

In the salesforce UI, there is a related list of opportunities on contact layout. However, I can't figure out an API field that relates contact and opportunity.

I basically want to get all opportunities for a contact that I see on the contact page in Salesforce UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of OpportunityContactRole to get the opportunities for a particular contact. Like: `Select OpportunityId from OpportunityContactRole where contactID`